# Auto-Update ASP.NET application to clients local server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-deployment, auto-update

I have a asp.net web application that has been deployed in the local IIS server of clients. These clients are more than 100 in number as of yet.

Since the application is in early phase of release, it gets updated almost on a daily basis. It becomes cumbersome to deploy new updates to each client's server individually.

Therefore, I would like to implement a mechanism where the user can automatically check for updates, download and replace the IIS application file.

I did try the solution given in this article [Building a Self Updating Site Using NuGet](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx/) but it felt as if it wasn't very reliable and scalable.

So any help on this would be highly appreciated. 
Many Thanks.

Comment: Why did it feel unreliable or not scalable? What's wrong with creating your own custom deployment scripts?

Comment: Have you thought about using Web Deploy in some sort of powershell script? http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets

Comment: Couldn't you use some type of subversion control system? http://git-scm.com/

Comment: @mason The concept of packaging the whole web application into a nuget package and then deploying it just didn't feel right to me. I coudln't find any examples of it being used in large scale applications either. Besides the "AutoUpdated" package itself has not been updated since last 2 years. 
Regarding, creating my own custom deployment scripts. I am trying to read as much resources as possible as to how it can be achieved. Any directions will be highly welcomed.

Comment: @NabinKarkiThapa Deployment is highly specific to your environment and the tools you feel comfortable with. How do *you* want to deploy? That's for you to decide, not us.

Comment: @SheldonNeilson No, I had no idea about it. I am going through the link right now. Thanks !